# Should tags for a deprecated library reference the deprecation?

Tags: support, tags, tag-wiki

From https://vue-native.io:

> ⚠️ Vue Native has been deprecated and is no longer maintained.

Should the [vue-native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vue-native) tag description mention this?

Comment: I think yes, why not?

Comment: In fact, I'd put it at the top. Is there a replacement? If so, that should also be mentioned.

Comment: For the wiki, certainly. For the excerpt, possibly, but that should mainly focus on what the tag means and when using it is appropriate. I'd mention it like _Vue Native is a deprecated framework to..._

Comment: The excerpt should be dedicated to explain when to use the tag, other information should be just shoved to the wiki.

Comment: Ugh, the original tag wiki is plagiarized

Comment: We can solve that by plagiarizing the deprecation warning, right, @Zoe?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It can be mentioned in the **full tag wiki**, but should not be mentioned in the **tag wiki excerpt**.

The help box on the top right of the [tag info editing page](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-tag-wiki/133497) describes what belongs on each part of the wiki:

> #### What are Tag Wikis?
>
> The **usage guidance**, or **tag wiki excerpt**, is a short blurb that describes **when and why a tag should be used on this site specifically**.
>
> The **full tag wiki** is a detailed introduction to the topic, suitable as a destination for those curious about it:
>
> ► what questions should have this tag?
>
> ► some basic definitions
>
> ► brief introduction to the subject
>
> ► important links for learning more
>
> ► one reasonably sized page
>
> See our advice on [writing great tag wikis](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/03/24/redesigned-tags-page/).

(Some emphasis added)

While there is no specific reference to "software deprecation" on that guidance, the list cannot possibly be all inclusive.

But it does mention *"a detailed introduction to the topic, suitable to those curious about it"*, *"basic definitions"*, or *"important links for learning more"*, for example; which I think readily cover "this library/project/api/whatever has been deprecated in favour of Foo since Nov 11th 2002", for example.

Comment: where is there reference to project status in the quote you provided?